# Magento2: How to overwrite vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Tags: magento2

Magento2: How to overwrite

```
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do following steps

1 . Add phtml file in your layout xml file

```
<action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::configurable.phtml</argument>
</action>
```

2. After that add `configurable.phtml` file in your `module/view/frontend/templates/` folder

**Note : Clear cache**

For more information [click here](https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/)

Comment: nothing happens after following the steps above.

Comment: @Tora did you find any solution? Please share.